# Why WCF Service run application locally instead of network?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, iis-express, ibm-doors

I have a SOAP api at the remote computer which is for runnig IBM Doors application and dxl scripts in a website (company private network). I hosted my application at the IIS Server with dxlApiPool (*Managed pipeline mode: Integrated*, *Identity: NetworkService*).

My problem is that **every time when I try to run dxl script, dxlApi open Doors application with my username at the remote computer locally and it cannot be authenticated.** I want to run this application as a network service.

> Error: **"Access denied: DOORS session is not authenticated at
> DOORSCOMLib.DOORSClass.runStr(String dxlFragment) at
> DxlSoapApi.DxlService.runStr(String dxlText)"**

I realize this line in the code maybe cause of that problem:

```
Activatior.CreateInstance(typeof(DOORSClass)) as IDoorsDxl;
```

Comment: This seems like an authentication or permissions problem. I am not sure how doors works, but are you authenticated locally ?

Comment: @TheGeneral I give username and password info in the ProcessStartInfo() and when I run Process.Start() line, it should be automatically authenticate, I should not do any local authentication process.

Comment: There is a similar problem in this link you can refer to it: https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/question/0D50z00006HIM0y/doors-connection-from-wcf-service?language=zh_CN